# Need Debug Logs of Last Month

Tags: apex, trigger, debugging

We have a production issue which was occurred a month back and he raised it now with out any steps to reproduce. and we are unable to reproduce so 
 is there any chance of getting the debug logs of last month. so that we can cross check the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Just raise a Case to Salesforce Support. Well Its not possible to get the debug logs for last month however support can try to get the network logs or splunk logs for that month which can point the issue and can help in rectifying

Comment: I too raised a case and they have this service for only premium customer it seems any way thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is No. System debug logs are retained for 24 hours. Monitoring debug logs are retained for seven days.

So there are no chances you can get one month old debug logs. You can raise a case to support but I don't think that will help but still you can try.